# Issues of Parse Email and Save Attachments into directory

Tags: php

I am using this script(http://stuporglue.org/mailreader-php-parse-e-mail-and-save-attachments-php-version-2/) to save email attachment on my server. You can also view the complete script on browser here: http://stuporglue.org/downloads/mailReader.txt

Everything works fine but there are 2 problems here.

1) The file name of the image that i saved into the directory is not an image: 1360341823_test_jpg

```
How to convert the file name from 1360341823_test_jpg to 1360341823_test.jpg 
in the script?
```

2) The permission of the file that saved in the directory is 600.

```
How to make it default 755 or 775?
```

I believe this is the function to convert the image in the script.:

```
function saveFile($filename,$contents,$mimeType){
global $save_directory,$saved_files,$debug;
$filename = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/','_',$filename);

$unlocked_and_unique = FALSE;
  while(!$unlocked_and_unique){
    // Find unique
    $name = time()."_".$filename;
      while(file_exists($save_directory.$name)) {
        $name = time()."_".$filename;
      }

    // Attempt to lock
    $outfile = fopen($save_directory.$name,'w');
      if(flock($outfile,LOCK_EX)){
        $unlocked_and_unique = TRUE;
      } else {
        flock($outfile,LOCK_UN);
        fclose($outfile);
      }
  }

fwrite($outfile,$contents);
fclose($outfile);

  // This is for readability for the return e-mail and in the DB
  $saved_files[$name] = Array(
    'size' => formatBytes(filesize($save_directory.$name)), 
    'mime' => $mimeType
  );
}
```

Any help?

Comment: You may consider the use of this Python script: https://github.com/auino/mail-attachments-archiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original script used the data to store in the DB but I think you are trying to save it in the file. You are creating the file without extension here:

```
 // Attempt to lock
    $outfile = fopen($save_directory.$name,'w');
```

Either add the .jpg after the line as:

```
 #outfile.=".jpg";
```

Other way if you don't want to change script then you can get use as:

```
 $contents = file_get_contents($save_directory.$name);
 $outfile = fopen($save_directory.$new_name,'w');
 write($outfile,$contents);
 fclose($outfile);
```

This would resolve your first problem and for second question kindly use the FTP or Control panel provided to access the files to change the ownership rights. If you don't know about any thing then you contact your Web Hosting Service Provider to share the ownership from 755 to 775